# Show red star for invalid fields

Tags: angularjs, css-selectors

I want to add a red star before invalid text inputs.
Something like

```
.ng-invalid:before
    { 
        content: "*"; 
        color: Red; 
    }
```

unfortunately it seems that :before doesn't always work for input.
How to do?

Comment: You'll have to add width and height too!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field

Answer (score 0):

*removed*

**edit**

You need to put the elements in a div and give that the `:before` properties, *or* just have it in a separate element (the `*`) which uses `ng-show` for validity.

Misunderstood the question initially, but yes, this.

Comment: Suppose I put the input element in a div. How am I going to select this div, since css doesn't have parent selectors.

Comment: You would have to change your way of going about this (e.g. by having a red border instead), or use an `ng-show` condition on a class or element for when `$invalid` is true for that control.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
In order to make the solution reusable, I have created the directive: ngErrorShow
It adds a star element before the input, and uses ngShow, to show/ hide the star.

```
portaldirectives.directive("ngErrorShow", function ($compile) { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'A', 
        require: "^form", 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) { 
            var varName = ctrl.$name + "." + attrs.name + ".$valid";           
            var a_input = angular.element($compile('<span style="color:red" ng-show="!' + varName + '" >*</span>')(scope)); 
            element.parent().prepend(a_input); 
        } 
    }; 
});
```